# ~30 second logon for Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, login, performance

I have quite a reasonably spec'd machine:

- i7-2600k @4Ghz
- OCZ Velocity 3 ssd
- 1tb cavier black hdd

#### The issue:

The 'welcome' logon screen takes ~30sec to finish and bring me to desktop and it should be much faster than that. Booting to the login screen is faster than this.

#### Confguration:

Windows 7 64bit installed on the ssd, which is the boot drive. Users folder for Downloads has been redirected to the 1tb hdd. Minimal to no startup programs (brand new machine)
[image]

#### What it's not:

It is not the desktop background bug, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977346

#### What I think it has to do with:

The user folder redirection, however for the life of my searching all I come up with are domain admins having issues with their user folder redirection, but these are for a remote machine, not a separate drive.

So I'm sure I'm not the first win7 64bit user who has the os on a ssd and has redirected one or more of the users folders to a hdd. Any asasist, or diagnosing tools would be great.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx or try http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/117154-trace-vista-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/ and hopefully xperf will keep tracing past the logon screen.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to switch methodologies. You should get Process monitor and have it log the processes that fire up on boot up.

You say **minimal** startup processes.  But you should list them anyways.  While unlikely, a single process could crush your startup times.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I can think of:

- Check the system event logs to see what services are taking a lot time to start. My guess is anti-virus.
- Maybe your user profile/registry files are corrupted. This should be reflected in event logs as well.
- It is possible that your SSD has too many bad blocks on it and is having a degraded performance. Check its SMART info or do a performance benchmark to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my i7-920 Windows 7 64-bit machine when I first installed it also. I found that uninstalling my hard disk driver in device manager and then rebooting fixed the issue. I would try that it worked for me, I never looked far enough into it to determine why it was causing that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the use of an SSD on your Windows machine with SSD Tweaker:

http://elpamsoft.com/Downloads.aspx?Name=SSD%20Tweaker

For the bootup process to be faster you can disable some startup processes that are not important. You can control all of your startup process with Sysinternals Autoruns:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902